# Unable to validate data, EncryptOrDecryptData error

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, webresource.axd

I am getting hundreds of the following errrors on the production server (IIS7.5, .net 4.5 web app):

> Exception type: System.Web.HttpException Exception message: Unable to
>   validate data. Request URL: 
>   http://mydomain.com/WebResource.axd?d=vIkcOYaxqSd6eMCUlxDkdQVxjxcaRV8fWPLFaNn8W4w1&t=633802992069218315&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1
>   Request path: /WebResource.axd Stack trace: at
>   System.Web.Configuration.MachineKeySection.EncryptOrDecryptData(Boolean
>   fEncrypt, Byte[] buf, Byte[] modifier, Int32 start, Int32 length,
>   Boolean useValidationSymAlgo, Boolean useLegacyMode, IVType ivType,
>   Boolean signData)

They began after I migrated the site from .net 3.5 to .net 4, then 4.5. This is the machineKey element in web.config:

> machineKey validationKey="KeyA" decryptionKey="KeyB" validation="SHA1"
>   compatibilityMode="Framework20SP1"

Do I need to generate new machinekeys? If so, what do I do about aspnet Membership passwords? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How long has it been since the site migration took place?  Do you have 3.5 / 4.0 / 4.5 servers all together in a web farm?

Comment: The migration happened last Xmas and there is no web farm. All applications running in IIS are .net 4.5.

Comment: So have you managed to solve your problem? I'm having a similar one.

Comment: So have you managed to solve your problem? I'm having a similar one, Kindly update the post. I have version 3.5 / 4.0 / 4.5 all together in web farm.